# How to do a select *, <other_expressions> using Oracle NoSQL?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am executing the following query (test table) :

```
select * from users order by id;
{"id":1,"firstname":"David","lastname":"Morrison","age":25,"income":100000}
{"id":2,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Anderson","age":35,"income":100000}
{"id":3,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Morgan","age":38,"income":null}
{"id":4,"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Smith","age":38,"income":80000}
{"id":5,"firstname":"Dana","lastname":"Scully","age":47,"income":400000}
```

Now I want to add a new column calling modification_time($u). So I've tried

```
select *, modification_time($u)  as mt from users $u order by id;
```

it is failing with a syntax error, so I've tried

```
select $u.*, modification_time($u)  as mt from users $u order by id;
```

it is failing with a syntax error too

FYI, the following query is working

```
select modification_time($u) as mt from users $u order by id;
```

The idea is to have the same result as for this query but without needing specify all fields

```
select id , firstname, lastname, age, income,  modification_time($u)  as mt from users $u order by id;
{"id":1,"firstname":"David","lastname":"Morrison","age":25,"income":100000,"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.326Z"}
{"id":2,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Anderson","age":35,"income":100000,"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.332Z"}
{"id":3,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Morgan","age":38,"income":null,"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.336Z"}
{"id":4,"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Smith","age":38,"income":80000,"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.338Z"}
{"id":5,"firstname":"Dana","lastname":"Scully","age":47,"income":400000,"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.340Z"}
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The only expression that returns a row is a row variable, that is, a table alias whose name starts with '$'.You are already using this when calling the modification_time($u), so you just need to use this variable in your select.

```
select $u, modification_time($u)  as mt 
from users $u order by id;
```

In your case, it will be return a record with all
the fields (select *) + your expressions

```
{"u":{"id":1,"firstname":"David","lastname":"Morrison","age":25,"income":100000},"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.326Z"}
{"u":{"id":2,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Anderson","age":35,"income":100000},"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.332Z"}
{"u":{"id":3,"firstname":"John","lastname":"Morgan","age":38,"income":null},"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.336Z"}
{"u":{"id":4,"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Smith","age":38,"income":80000},"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.338Z"}
{"u":{"id":5,"firstname":"Dana","lastname":"Scully","age":47,"income":400000},"mt":"2021-06-18T08:39:08.340Z"}
```

I don't know if it is possible to have all fields at the same json "level" as you shown in your last output.

Hope that this can help